# how to set overflow scroll on div with unknown height

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have the following setup:

```css
.page {
  width: 360px;
height: 704px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

header {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  height: 90%;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container-dynamic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

p {
  text-aling: center;
}

.container-fill {
  width: 80%;
  
  border: 1px dashed black;
  
  height: auto;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  
}

.c {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  
  max-height: 100%;
  
  overflow: scroll;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.b {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header>
    HALLO
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container-dynamic">
      <p>This container has dynamic height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fill">
      <p>This container fills up the left space</p>
      <div class="c">
        <div class="b">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

now as you can see, the green area is way larger than the whole `.page` element. What I am trying to achieve is to make the green area fill the left space on the page. I achieved that with `flex: 1 1 auto` on `.c` and with `display: flex, flex-flow: column` on the `main` element. Additional to that, I need the green area to be scrollable,  when the children (here the lightblue rectangle `.b`) is too large to fit in it without overflow. But setting `overflow: scroll` on the green element doesnt have any effects and result in the given code sample. If anyone could help me out on how to achieve my goal, I would be very grateful.

---

Of course this can be achieved by calculating the remaining height via JavaScript, but Id like to know if theres a css-only method as well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.page {
  width: 360px;
height: 704px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

header {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  height: 90%;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container-dynamic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

p {
  text-aling: center;
}

.container-fill {
  width: 80%;
  
  border: 1px dashed black;
  
  height: 100%;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  
}

.c {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  
  max-height: 100%;
  
  overflow: scroll;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.scroll-elem-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header>
    HALLO
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container-dynamic">
      <p>This container has dynamic height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-elem-container">
      <div class="container-fill">
        <div class="c">
          <div class="b">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```